# c program to store the show command ouput into a string

Tags: c, parsing

I am executing "dmidecode" command in linux prompt and which will give the product information. I want to store the Product name and manufacturer name into two separate variables. I am using popen to execute the command.

Example: 
Using popen(dmidecode)
The output would be as below.

System Information

```
    ------snip--------
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP Compaq 1234 Elite SFF PC
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: 123456
```

I want to store Manufacturer info into one variable and Product Name into another variable.

Could you please give your ideas to implement the above scenario?.

I have not written the code fully, the sample code is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpipe;
    char *command = "dmidecode";
    char ch[50],manufacturer[50],productname[50];

    if ((fpipe = popen(command, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("popen() failed.");
        exit(1);
    }

    //read line by line
    while (fgets(ch,sizeof ch,fpipe))
    {
        // need to code
        printf("%s", ch);
    }
    pclose(fpipe);
    return -1;

}
```

I want to parse the output and fetch only the manufacturer and product information.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: pipe the output to your program, read stdin, parse it, store the part you want

Comment: @Pyjong ...that belongs to: **Too broad** There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @LPs You may wanna tell that to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fpipe;
  char *command = "dmidecode";
  char ch[100]={0}, manufacturer[50]={0}, productname[50]={0}, *m, *p;

  if ((fpipe = popen (command, "r")) == NULL)
    {
      printf ("popen() failed.");
      exit (1);
    }

  //read line by line
  while (fgets (ch, sizeof ch, fpipe))
    {
      if (m = strstr (ch,"Manufacturer"))
        {
          strcpy (manufacturer, m + strlen ("Manufacturer: "));
        }
      if (p = strstr (ch, "Product Name"))
        {
          strcpy (productname, p + strlen ("Product Name: "));
        }
    }
  pclose (fpipe);
  printf ("%s", manufacturer);
  printf ("%s", productname);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pramod.! Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

```
sscanf(ch, "Manufacturer: %[^\n]", manufacturer);
```

It will scan the text in `ch` using the format string `"Manufacturer: %[^\n]"`. The format string tells `sscanf` to skip the first part of the text, which **should** be `Manufacturer:`. Then, `%[^\n]` tells it to store the rest into your `manufacturer` array variable. One thing to note here is, if the input text **doesn't** match the format string (doesn't start with `Manufacturer:`), `sscanf` will report that in its return value (0 = "failure"; 1 = "decoded 1 field").

So you can use this:

```
int result;
result = sscanf(ch, "Manufacturer: %[^\n]", manufacturer);
result = sscanf(ch, "Product Name: %[^\n]", product_name);
if (result == 1)
{
    // Just decoded the product name.
    // Must have decoded the manufacturer earlier (if the file format was OK)
    printf("Decoded %s and %s\n", manufacturer, product_name);
}
```